# How to iterate JSON Array in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have this below type of array. I want to iterate this array in JavaScript. How is this possible?

```
{
"result": true,
"data": [
{
    "ID": 1,
    "stage_ID": 1,
    "badge_type_ID": 1,
    "name": "Despertar da Força",
    "description": "Fazer a primeira SuperAtividade",
    "type": "",
    "image_static": "url123.jpg",
    "image_animated": "",
    "SQL": "",
    "published": 1
},
{
    "ID": 2,
    "stage_ID": 1,
    "badge_type_ID": 1,
    "name": "Super 3",
    "description": "Fazer 3 SuperAtividades",
    "type": "",
    "image_static": "urlimage123.png",
    "image_animated": "",
    "SQL": "",
    "published": 1
}
```

etc

I tried the following script and it is returning "undefined", "undefined".

```
$.getJSON('https://www.legiaodossuperpoderes.com.br/chronus/api/adm/badges', function(data) {
        var output= "<ol>";
        for (var i in data) {
            output += "<li>" + data[i].ID + "</li>"
        }
        output+="</ol>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
    });
```

Any solutions ? Thanks!

Comment: i suppose, that `function(data)` contains the whole object. you need a reference to data of the object.

Comment: try console.log(data) to double check data return from getJSON

Comment: try `data=data.data`. And `data[i]` is properly a mistake because `i` is the value of the array not index.

Comment: @gdlmx i is not value of array it is index. if u use for(var i of data) mean it will be value of array

Answer (score 2):

You can try converting to Json Object

```
$.getJSON('https://www.legiaodossuperpoderes.com.br/chronus/api/adm/badges', function(data) {
        var output= "<ol>";
        var jsondata = $.JSON.parse(data); // Json object Convertion
        for (var i in data) {
            output += "<li>" + data[i].ID + "</li>"
        }
        output+="</ol>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an undefined property using **data[i].ID** .

When you are getting response from your **getJSON()** function then you need to call the response with a name and then you can access any inner property using this name .

Now if you want to iterate using **data** key/value on myResponse variable then you need to do this.

```
$.getJSON('https://www.legiaodossuperpoderes.com.br/chronus/api/adm/badges', function(myResponse) {
    var output= "<ol>";
    var dataCount = myResponse.data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) {
        output += "<li>" + myResponse.data[i].ID + "</li>";
    }
    output+="</ol>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
});
```